# Let $f(x,y) = (y-x^{2})(y-2x^{2})$. Show that on any straight line through $(0,0)$ $f$ has a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = (y-x^{2})(y-2x^{2})$. Show that on any straight line through $(0,0)$ $f$ has a minimum at $(0,0)$, but that $f$ itself doesn't have a minimum at $(0,0).

This is a question from my multivariable analysis course. Currently it is still early in the semester and we've only finished discussing continuity. Following is my attempts(or lack of) to the two parts of the question:

**a) straight line**

For this part I simply said, let $y = cx$ for some constant $c$. From there I got $$f(x,cx) = c^{2}x^{2} - 3cx^{3} + 2x^{4}$$ after simplifying. So from calculus in order to find a minimum we would have to calculate the derivative and find any critical points, since this is now a function in one variable I can do that: $$f'(x) = 2c^{2}x - 9cx^{2} + 8x^{3}$$. Fortunately the point we are studying the behaviour at, $(0,0)$, is a critical point and we don't have to do any algebra. TO test the behaviour of the slope to the left and right of $0$ you just choose candidate points. We choose $-1$ and $1$ and they show: $$f'(-1) = -(2c^{2} + 9c - 9) \\ f'(1) = (2c^{2} + 9c - 9)$$

More importantly regardless of the value of $c$ the signs on the values do not change. So the function slopes downwards to the left of $0$ and slopes upwards to the right of $0$. This shows us that $(0,0)$ is a minimum along any straight line.

**b) the function $f$ itself**

This is where the trouble starts. I've done a course in multivariable calculus before so the only way I know of to obtain the minimum would be through taking the partial derivatives and calculating the Hessian. But there is no way this can be what is expected of us because we are nowhere near "defining" multi-dimensional derivatives. So this being the case, how would I approach this problem?

Comment: For (a), two issues:

First, you're missing the vertical line $x=0$.

Second, this:

$$\text{ More importantly regardless of the value of c the signs on the values do not change. }$$

is false.

Comment: Then it appears I didn't this analyze correctly at all then.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0,0)=0$. The idea is to find points arbitrarly closed to $(0,0)$ in which the function $f$ has positive and negative values. For example, $f(0,\varepsilon)=\varepsilon^2>0$ for any $\varepsilon\neq 0$.

On the other hand, $f(\sqrt{\varepsilon},\frac{3\varepsilon}{2}) = -\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}<0$ for any $\varepsilon >0$.